# How to avoid repeating a chunk of code in Django views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

What is the best way to avoid repeating a chunk of code that is being used in more than one class view?

I'm repeating these 2 lines in couple of classes.

```
moderator = ServerModerator.objects.get(user=request.user)
server = Server.objects.get(Q(creator=request.user) | Q(moderators=moderator), Q(tag=server_tag))
```

I've tried to create a function inside `models.py` like this:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    ...
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_servers')
    moderators = models.ManyToManyField('ServerModerator', related_name='server')

    def moderator_checker(self, current_user):
        moderator = ServerModerator.objects.get(user=current_user)
        server = Server.objects.get(Q(creator=current_user) | Q(moderators=moderator),Q(tag=self.tag))
        return server
```

but this doesn't work.

**views.py:**

```
class TagsAndFlairsView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
form_class = CreatePostTagForm
form_class_2 = CreateUserTagForm

def get(self, request, server_tag):
    ...
    # moderator = ServerModerator.objects.get(user=request.user)
    # server = Server.objects.get(Q(creator=request.user) | Q(moderators=moderator), Q(tag=server_tag))
    check = Server.moderator_checker(request.user)
    server_post_tags = check.post_tags.all()
    server_user_tags = check.user_tags.all()
    return render(request, 'servers/tags-flairs.html', {"server":check, "server_post_tags":server_post_tags, "server_user_tags":server_user_tags, "create_post_tag_form":create_post_tag_form, "create_user_tag_form":create_user_tag_form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom queryset:

```
class ServerQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def check_moderator(self, current_user, tag):
        moderator = get_object_or_404(ServerModerator, user=current_user)
        self = self.get(Q(creator=current_user) | Q(moderators=moderator),Q(tag=tag))
        return self
```

Then in your Server model, define:

```
objects = ServerQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Now you can do:

```
server = Server.objects.check_moderator(request.user, tag) # EXAMPLE OF USER
```

QuerySets also allow you to do a few other things. You can now for example; filter down the results before checking if the user is a moderator.
This is great for example, if you have an 'active' field or anything of the sorts. `Server.objects.filter(server_is_active=True).check_moderator(request.user, tag)`.

> `Note:` Generally, it is better to use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of `get()` as it *calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises [Http404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/#django.http.Http404) instead of the model’s [DoesNotExist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) exception*.

Comment: Thank you so much this is working perfectly. could you please give me a link to Django documents for more information about custom querysets?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager

Comment: yes you are right i forgot to add that instead of get :)